# Is $\frac{1}{(\log n)^{n^p}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ratio

Is $\frac{1}{(\log(n))^{n^p}}$ convergent or divergent? My solution:

Use ratio test $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|=\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{(\log(n))^{(n)^{p}}}{(\log(n+1))^{(n+1)^{p}}}|$

Since we know that as n goes to infinity $\log(n+1)>\log(n)$ and $(n+1)^{p}>n^{p}$, so  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|<1$$ and it should converge.

Is that correct?

Comment: your argument says that the ratio is $>1$, which does not necessarily imply that the limit is $>1$

Comment: Ratio test, what for ? The word series is not even present in your wording. Or maybe we have to guess from the tags ? As is, I just say that $\log(n)\to +\infty$ thus $\frac 1{\log(n)^{n^p}}\to 0$.

Comment: You are better off using the root test here. It will give you the exact range of p's for which the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect as you flipped your ratio upside down. Your RHS in the limit is the inverse of the LHS. Also listen to what pirate is telling you. You must also evaluate the limit.

EDIT: Here is a hint to evaluating the limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)^{n^p}}{\log(n+1)^{(n+1)^p}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{{\log(\log(n)^{n^p}) -\log(\log(n+1)^{(n+1)^p}})}$$
Now try to use some more logarithm properties to find for which values of $p$ this ratio is less than 1.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the upside down mistake. How should I evaluate that ratio? Any suggestions?

Comment: It is normally helpful to take the logarithm when faced with strange exponents such as this. If you need a walk-through of the full solution, just ask.